# How to change Neovim config directory

Tags: neovim

My current config file is at

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\nvim`

But I set up a new config setup in `C:\Users\User\.config\nvim`

How can I change it so that the config directory reflects this change? Thanks!

Comment: `:h base-directories`

Answer (score 10):

In neovim 0.9.0 it was included support for environment variable **NVIM_APPNAME** that allows configuring the config file location

For instance, by setting **NVIM_APPNAME=nvim-v2**, config files will be in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\nvim-v2

Reference: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/22128

Comment: I have been looking for this damned env var for the past 2 days. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know,
neovim looks for init.vim in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim directory

(which in windows is at ~/AppData/Local/nvim) so the $XDG_CONFIG_HOME variable is responsible for that.

In my opinion, if all you want to do is change neovim's config specifically a symbolic link will do the job:)